# Vim: delete empty lines around cursor

Tags: vim

Suppose I'm editing the following document (* = cursor):

```
Lions
Tigers


Kittens
Puppies


*


  Humans
```

What sequence can I use to delete the surrounding white space so that I'm left with:

```
Lions
Tigers


Kittens
Puppies
*
  Humans
```

Note: I'm looking for an answer that handles any number of empty lines, not just this exact case.

**EDIT 1:** Line numbers are unknown and I only want to effect the span my cursor is in.

**EDIT 2:** Edited example to show I need to preserve leading whitespace on edges

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for some solution by script/command? This case is too easy if doing manually. If so, better to provide more info, say why the cursor is there?

Comment: is current line (under cursor) always empty line?

Comment: @Billy Chan, unless your manual way can be done with 1 universal mapping, I'd have to disagree with it being 'too easy'. Cursor is there because it ended up there :)

Comment: I can't see the pattern why cursor is there, which makes it hard to figure out an universal mapping

Comment: @BillyChan I'm just moving the cursor around the document. I may have <C-D>'ed into the empty area.

Comment: I don't see why it matters _why_ the cursor is there.  The OP wants to delete all consecutive empty (or maybe all whitespace) lines above and below the cursor.  That seems pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy. In normal mode, `dipO<Esc>` should do it.

Explanation:

- `dip` on a blank line deletes it and all adjacent blank lines.
- `O<Esc>` opens a new empty line, then goes back to normal mode.

Even more concise, **`cip<Esc>`** would roll these two steps into one, as suggested by @Lorkenpeist.

Comment: By far the cleanest and most intuitive solution. +1

Comment: As long as you have more than one empty space `vipJ` works and it avoids going into insert mode.

Comment: Brilliant!  Slightly better: `cip<Esc>`

Comment: @Lorkenpeist Goodness yes, why didn't I think of that?!

Comment: Best part is `cip<esc>` can be repeated with `.`! Although if I had an entire file of this space squeezing I would still do `:v/./,//-j`

Comment: +1 it is short and clean answer to the question. @Lorkenpeist maybe you could consider to accept it.

Answer (score 7):

A possible solution is to use the `:join` command with a range:

```
:?.?+1,/./-1join!
```

Explanation:

- `[range]join!` will join together a `[range]` of lines. The `!` means with out inserting any extra space.
- The starting point is to search backwards to the first character then down 1 line, `?.?+1`
- As the `1` in `+1` can be assumed this can be abbreviated `?.?+`
- The ending point is to search forwards to the next character then up 1 line, `/./-1`
- Same as before the `1` can be assumed so, `/./-`
- As we are using the same pattern only searching forward the pattern can be omitted. `//-`
- The command `:join` can be shorted to just `:j`

Final shortened command:

```
:?.?+,//-j!
```

Here are some related commands that might be handy:

1) to delete all empty lines:

- `:g/^$/d`
- `:v/./d`

2) Squeeze all empty lines into just 1 empty line:

- `:v/./,//-j`

For more help see:

```
:h :j
:h [range]
:h :g
:h :v
```

Comment: even though the `c/dip` answer suits better to this question, your `?.?` searching backwards is nice too. I didn't think of it. +1

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer:** `()V)kc<esc>`

In normal mode, if you type `()` your cursor will move to the first blank line.  `(` moves the cursor to the beginning of the previous block of non-blank lines, and `)` moves the cursor to the end (specifically, to the first blank line after said block).  Then a simple `d)` will delete all text until the beginning of the next non-blank line.  So the complete sequence is `()d)`.

EDIT: You're right, that deletes the whitespace at the beginning of the next non-blank line.  Instead of `d)` try `V)kd`.  `V` puts you in visual line mode, `)` jumps to the first non-blank line (skipping the whitespace at the beginning of the line), `k` moves the cursor up one line.  At this point you've selected all the blank lines, so `d` deletes the selection.

Finally, type `O` (capital O) followed by escape to crate a new blank line to replace the ones you deleted.  Alternatively, replacing `dO<Escape>` with `c<Escape>` does the same thing with one less keystroke, so the entire sequence would be `()V)kc<Esc>`.

Comment: Awesome, this one is close. This also deletes the leading whitespace from the next non-blank line. Thoughts on how to avoid that? @Lorkenpeist

Comment: The OP also wants to delete all the blank lines _above_ the cursor.

Comment: @jahroy I think this sequence does that actually. It's just deleting a bit too much now.

Comment: Ok, that's great.  Although, based on your question it looks like you want to keep one blank line (where the cursor is).  Maybe that's not the case.

Comment: @jahroy Ah I do want to keep the cursor on the blank line. Didn't notice that (was too focused on the leading whitespace issue)

Comment: This seems to remove **ALL** blank lines above and below the cursor position, **including the line the cursor is on**.

Comment: @Conner `kkd` will delete non-whitespace if there is only a single blank line.

Comment: @Peter That's brilliant, except that it also doesn't work for a single blank line.  I really wanted that one to work :(

Comment: @Lorkenpeist I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish by having it work with a single blank line. Try my solution with substitute in my answer if you want to have this type of functionality in a widespread fashion.

Answer (score 1):

### These answers are irrelevant after the updated question:

This may not be the answer you want to hear, but I would make use of ranges. Take a look at the line number for the first empty line (let's say 55 for example) and the second to last empty line (perhaps 67). Then just do `:55,67d`.

Or, perhaps you only want there to ever be one empty line in your whole file. In that case you can match any occurrence of one or more empty lines and replace them with one empty line.

```
:%s/\(^$\n\)\+/\r/
```

### This answer works:

If you just want to use normal mode you could search for the last line with something on it. For instance,

```
/.<Enter>kkVNjd
```

Comment: Thanks Conner. Yeah not what I'm looking for. I don't know the line numbers, and I expect more white space. I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: That doesn't work if there's only one blank line, it actually ends up deleting some real text.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test so much, but it should work for your examples. There maybe more elegant solutions.

```
function! DelWrapLines()
    while match(getline('.'),'^\s*$')>=0
        exe 'normal kJ'
    endwhile
    exe 'silent +|+,/./-1d|noh'
    exe 'normal k'
endfunction
```

source it and try `:call DelWrapLines()`

Comment: This is actually causing vim to hang. Can you break it down a bit to help troubleshoot?

Comment: @thedeeno I tested once in office. It worked.  Strange. I am on my way home now. Cannot do further test. Sorry if it boorthered u. I am gonna check it again when I am home.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has already been resolved, but I just found a great solution in "sed & awk, 2nd Ed." (O'Reilly) that I thought was worth sharing.  It does not use vim at all, but instead uses sed.  This script will replace all instances of one or more blank lines (assuming there is no whitespace in those lines) with a single blank line.  On the command line:

```
sed '/ˆ$/{
N
/ˆ\n$/D
}' myfile
```

Keep in mind that sed does not actually edit the file, but instead prints the edited lines to standard output.  You can redirect this input to a file:

```
sed '/ˆ$/{
N
/ˆ\n$/D
}' myfile > tempfile
```

Be careful though, if you try to write it directly to `myfile`, it will just delete the entire contents of the file, which is clearly not what you want!  After you write the output to `tempfile`, you can just `mv tempfile myfile` and tada!  All instances of multiple blank lines are replaced by a single blank line.

**Even better:**

```
cat -s myfile > temp
mv temp myfile
```

cat is awesome, yes?

**Bestest:**

If you want to do it inside vim, you can replace all instances of multiple blank lines with a single blank line by using vim's handy feature of executing shell commands on a range of lines within vim.

```
:%!cat -s
```

That's all it takes, and your entire file is reformatted all nice!