# What can follow "d" in normal mode?

Tags: vim

In an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369088/vim-delete-empty-lines-around-cursor), I learned that all empty lines around the cursor can be deleted using the key sequence <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> in normal mode. Astonished, I looked into the vim help, but the vim help only says that <kbd>d</kbd> may be followed by a movement, which clearly <kbd>i</kbd> isn't (it brings you to insert mode normally).

1. What exactly is <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> doing? What does <kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd> stand for in this context?
2. Where can I find it documented? What other "magic" characters can follow <kbd>d</kbd>?

Comment: please show what you have tried..

Comment: I suggest you read chapters two to four of the user manual to learn the basic Vim commands: [`:h usr_02`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_02.html) to start. It's a very good intro (and you'll find the answer there, too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use Vim as you'd think, speak or write with a normal spoken language.

You have verbs like `d[elete]`, `y[ank]`, `p[ut]`, `c[hange]`, `v[isually select]` and so on.

You have all sorts of objects like `w[ord]`, `p[aragraph]`, `t[ag]` and so on.

You have modifiers like `i[nner]`, `a[round]`, `t[ill]` or `/foo`  and many others and the ability to use a `{count}` as quantifier.

`dip` means "delete inner paragraph". `vat` means "[visually ]select the current HTML tag", `c2t;` means "change from here to the second next semicolon"…

Like with a real language, learning full sentences won't get you very far. The basic vocabulary is not that large so it is a good idea to forget about `dip` and learn about `d`, `i` and `p` instead. Learning `dip`, `ciB`, `gU/foo` and their millions of friends as single commands takes more time and brain cells than learning the individual commands and the simple grammar that make it all work.

Once you know `dcyv` (verbs), `ia` (modifiers) and `p` (object), learning a new object like `)` gives you instantly `di)`, `da)`, `ci)`, `ca)`, `vi)`, `va)` and so on. Each time you learn a new object or modifier (most often a single character), *your vocabulary increases dramatically*. Isn't that freaking cool?

Also, `:help d` and `:help ip` would have given you your answer.

As I like to say, "`:help motion.txt` will blow your mind".

Comment: Ah, what I was not aware of is that there are also those "objects" that can follow. Yes, the given help page will be good for continuing reading, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Think of [<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#dip) as ["**d**-elete"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#d) ["**i**-nner **p**-aragraph"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#ip),  where ["inner paragraph"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#ip) is a special kind of [motion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) called "[Text object selection](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#object-select)".

There are many, many "[motion](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html)s" in Vim, which you can learn about by reading [`:help motion`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) or (as I did many moons ago) by using [`vimtutor`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_01.html#vimtutor) (and using Vim every day).

Comment: @DanielJung: N.B: The mnemonic is Vim's, not mine (follow the first link in my answer). Happy editing!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, "d" can be combined with characters that move the cursor, with the result of deleting to between the point and the destination.

In this case the "magic" is that 'ip' stands for "inner paragraph". As far as I can tell, it means "apply this to the paragraph you're in". (but it's not one that I've really come across before, sad to say)

The vim documentation is spotty, but this might be useful:
ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/doc/book/vimbook-OPL.pdf